# Convert JetPack compose component to ImageBitmap

Tags: android, canvas, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get the Image Bitmap from my composable.
In other words, I want to know the equivalent of

```
View.draw(Canvas canvas)
```

in JetPack compose

Comment: This is not the best solution but I found this
https://proandroiddev.com/create-bitmaps-from-jetpack-composables-bdb2c95db51